# Need to change vue-csv-import "map-fields" with select

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm using [vue-csv-import](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-csv-import) plugin. But I want to change column names with select tag. This is my code.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">    
    <select v-model="columntype" @change="onChange($event)">
      <option>Type1</option>
      <option>Type2</option>
    </select>
    <vue-csv-import
      v-model="csv"
      :autoMatchFields="true"
      :autoMatchIgnoreCase="true"
      :map-fields="columns"
    >
    </vue-csv-import>
    <div style="padding-top: 50px">
      <p>Results</p>
      {{ csv }}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueCsvImport } from "vue-csv-import";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueCsvImport,
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      if (event.target.value === "Type1") {
        this.columns = ["name", "Age", "grade"];
      } else if (event.target.value === "Type2") {
        this.columns = ["lastname", "year", "grade"];
      }
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      csv: null,
      columntype: "Type1",
      columns: ["name", "Age", "grade"],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Here what I want is to use the select change event for change columns. Nothing happens when I change select box. Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/csv-import-forked-iyu19x?file=/src/App.vue) I'm using vue 2 and can't use 3 due to limitations.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <template>
  <div id="app">
    <select :value="columntype" @change="onChange">
      <option>Type1</option>
      <option>Type2</option>
    </select>
    <vue-csv-import
      v-model="csv"
      :autoMatchFields="true"
      :autoMatchIgnoreCase="true"
      :map-fields="columns"
    >
    </vue-csv-import>
    <div style="padding-top: 50px">
      <p>Results</p>
      {{ csv }}
    </div>
    {{JSON.stringify(columns)}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { VueCsvImport } from "vue-csv-import";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    VueCsvImport,
  },
  methods: {
    onChange(event) {
      this.columntype = event.target.value;
      if (event.target.value === "Type1") {
        this.columns = ["name", "Age", "grade"];
      } else if (event.target.value === "Type2") {
        this.columns = ["lastname", "year", "grade"];
      }
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {
      csv: null,
      columntype: "Type1",
      columns: ["name", "Age", "grade"],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Seems like not changing with select change :'( can try it here https://codesandbox.io/s/csv-import-forked-iyu19x?file=/src/App.vue. And need else if since there are few more values

Comment: @vimuth answer updated. I changed one line in template and one line in onChange method. Explanations are in the code.

Comment: seems like not yet changing :'( added your answer to a sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/csv-import-forked-2nlbh8

Comment: @vimuth this time I tested and pasted the exact code from sandbox. at the bottom JSON.stringify changes when I change the selectbox. I didn't test csv file though. I just made state changes work.

Comment: million thanks for your effort but still not updating https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/32026152?key=4f2f22844ab65d36fdd2e471a3c98b8a

Comment: @vimuth We solved the state issue. it seems cvs library isn't synchronizing with state.

Comment: is there any way to reload it?

Comment: @vimuth it should work because new state rerenders it. Look into versions of the library I suspect vue2 compatibility issue.